# How to Implement linear search for 2D Arrays

Tags: java, algorithm

Hello~ can i ask what is wrong with this code? Im on my 2nd year college and I find it difficult thank you so much for the help!

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
 
    public static boolean search(Integer A[][], Integer x){
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
 
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        Integer A[][] = {
            {13, 17, 43, 76},
            {18, 14,  9, 21},
            { 1,  7,  6, 45},
            { 9, 65, 80, 33}
        };
 
        //true
System.out.println(LinearSearch2D.search(A, 6));
 
        //false
System.out.println(LinearSearch2D.search(A, 90));
    }
}
```

Comment: apparently the `search` method is not implemented - it only does `throw new UnsupportedOperationException()` (assuming posted code is the `LinearSearch2D` class)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the class name of this logic is LinearSearch2D. This means you need to implement the search(..) method. Currently, it is throwing:  throw new UnsupportedOperationException();

Do 2 for loops to iterate the 2d array.

Change this:

```
public static boolean search(Integer A[][], Integer x){
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
```

to this:

```
public static boolean search(Integer A[][], Integer x){
     // add 2 for loops here
     //i suppose this search need to return true if the element is found, otherwise return false. so do the if comparison inside the 2 for loops, 
     //and return true if you find the x
}
```

Answer (score 0):

there isn't anything exactly wrong with it, but the search() method currently does nothing.  You can replace throw new `UnsupportedOperationException();` with:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < A[i].length; j++) {
            if(A[i][j]==x){
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
```

the first loop repeats as many times as the number of arrays, the second one repeats as many times as the number of items in each 2d array, and the if statement checks if the item is the item you're searching.

It doesn't always return false because whenever a return statement is called the method stops.